# How internal specifier works

Tags: c#, internal

I just try to use Internal in my `BaseClass`, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) told me that the Internal Class can't be Instantiate in other method or class and produce an error, But why I can still Instantiate the `BaseClass` in method `Main()`?

TestAccess.cs

```
internal class BaseClass 
{
   public static int intM = 0;
}

class TestAccess 
{
   static void Main() 
   {
      BaseClass myBase = new BaseClass();   // CS0122 This should be an error because BaseClass is Internal class.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood MSDN. `internal` means that the class is only visible **within the assembly that contains it**. The example you posted is perfectly valid.

MSDN says,

> It is an error to reference a type or a member with internal access
>   **outside the assembly within which it was defined.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So it means I need two separate projects to make internal specifier works?

Comment: If you want to restrict visibility based on the assembly that contains it, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what `intenral` means.  `internal` items can be accessed from any file in the same assembly (that is project or DLL).  Having two classes in the same file are definitely in the same assembly.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx):

> The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members.
>   Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same
>   assembly

Answer (score 1):

[Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) is for access within the same assembly only. You will not get an error because you are in the same assembly (in this case the same file).

You will not be able to access `internal class BaseClass` if it was in another project.